# Can I fix the issue when I call an api, it called two times with reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, fetch

I used redux-saga and I want when I click on my button, the api will be fetching,

My code is:

```
// @flow
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Row, Col, Card, CardBody, Button, ButtonDropdown, Dropdown, DropdownToggle, DropdownMenu, DropdownItem } from 'reactstrap';
import { Translate } from 'src/components';
import { VCS } from 'src/common';
import { ACCESS_LEVELS, USER_RIGHTS, userAccess } from 'src/constants/user-rights';
import * as Actions from './actions';
import ClientUsersRSuiteTable from './components/client-users-rsuite-table';

import './users.scss';

    function Users({ clientId, clientUsers, requestClientUsersData, getUserTemplate, pageParameters, ...props }) {
      const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState('');
      useEffect(() => {
        requestClientUsersData({ id: clientId, pageParams: null });
      }, []);
    
      const handleChangeSearchValue = (input) => {
        const search = input != '' ? input : null;
        setSearchValue(search);
      };
      const [dropdownOpen, setDropdownOpen] = useState(false);
      const toggle = () => setDropdownOpen(prevState => !prevState);
    
      return (
        <>
          <VCS hasRights={[userAccess(ACCESS_LEVELS.EDIT, USER_RIGHTS.API_CLIENTS)]}>
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col">
                <Button
                  style={{ backgroundColor: '#ffffff !important', color: '#fa5c7c !important' }}
                  outline
                  color="danger"
                  className="mb-2 mr-1 btn-user-template"
                  onClick={() => getUserTemplate(clientId)}
                >
                  <i className="mdi mdi-file-outline mr-1" size="large" />
                  <Translate id="pages.client.users.get.user.template" />
                </Button>
              </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </VCS>
        </>
      );
    }
    
    Users.defaultProps = {
    };
    
    const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
      clientUsers: state.Administration.users.clientUsers ? state.Administration.users.clientUsers :
        state.Administration.clients.clientUsers,
      pageParameters: state.Administration.users.clientUsersPageParameters ? state.Administration.users.clientUsersPageParameters :
        state.Administration.clients.clientUsersPageParameters
    });
    
    export default connect(mapStateToProps, Actions)(Users);
```

My api is:

```
export const getUserTemplate = async (clientId) => request(`api/clients/${clientId}/users/import/template`, 'GET');
```

When I click on the button, my api is called two times with same response !

[image]

The Api is to export excel data, when I run it, I get :

[image]

I want when I run it on clicking the button, I get just one file not two(because it runs two time)

How can I fix it ?

Comment: I don't see a great reason your function that makes that API request would get called twice on a button click from the available code, is it possible some other part of your application is replicating the API call?